# Error: jdk1.7 or higher needed to run Google plugin for eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-app-engine, adt

I have been trying to make this work all day long but there seems to be no end to my frustration. I want to use Google App Engine for my android application. I have downloaded the jdk 1.7 u51 but still whenever i start the eclipse ADT, a dialog box appears saying that jdk 1.6 is in use; jdk 1.7 or higher needs to be installed. I have set the path in the preference to jre inside the jdk 1.7. Also, the app engine SDK path shows the error "Failed to initialize App Engine SDk[path]". I have referred all the threads here and over the internet relating to this issue and have tried all the proposed solutions but to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**versions**
eclipse 4.2(ADT)
JDK 1.7u51
App Engine SDK 1.8.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try uninstalling the old java version, and making sure that the latest version is the only one installed. Another problem might be if you have a 64-bit computer, you may have the older version installed to one program files, but Eclipse is looking through the x86 program files and not finding the correct version(or vice-versa). You may also want to set your PATH and CLASSPATH.

Type

```
java -version

javac -version
```

into the command prompt, and it will return with what Java you have installed.
If all else fails, try reading https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/installing for more information and see what went wrong.

Comment: @MoDrags follow this to set your Path and CLASSPATH http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html

Comment: I tried uninstalling the older versions of java i.e jre and jdk 6 as you said. Now the eclipse is not finding the java path and shows an error. After specifying the java path in ini file using vm, the error shows java was started but returned exit code=13. On checking the java -version on cmd, it says java is not recognised.

Comment: as Raj said, make sure that the JVM version (32/64 bit) you use matches the eclipse version (32/64 bit). If using 64-bit, don't forget to change the -vm argument to "C:/Program Files (x86)/" instead of "C:/Program Files/".

Comment: I have done exactly that. Everything matches but still the problem persists

Comment: Alright well I'm kind of stuck. I'm pretty sure it is something with the parameters. Check that this is the version being used by Eclipse, as shown in your error code. If not, call that version explicitly, e.g.

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe" -version

Comment: I fixed it. it was 32 bit and 64 bit thing all over again. there was a big confusion while setting the proper jdk. Thank you tyson and sorry for the late reply

Answer (score 0):

You must have matching architecture for Eclipse and JDK. If you are using 32-bit eclipse, then use 32-bit JDK else use 64-bit versions of both.

Everything else will fall in place automatically

Answer (score 0):

I am using Indigo and found [this forum thread](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/google-plugin-eclipse/V4MaZEXY24Q/discussion) to do the trick.

To your eclipse.ini file add

```
-vm
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_WHATEVERTHESUFFIXIS/Contents/Home/jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib
```

Note the suffix "lib/server/libjvm.dylib" which is not what you use for later versions of Eclipse. (For them you link to "bin/java".) This needs to be above any "-vmargs" flags in eclipse.ini.